# Conditional sum and product relationship

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For all real numbers $b$ and $c$, such that the product of $c$ and $3$ is $b$, which of the following expressions represents the sum of $c$ and $3$ in terms of $b$?
$$b+3$$
$$3b+3$$
$$3(b+3)$$
$$\frac{b+3}{3}$$
$$\frac{b}{3}+3$$

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange., The custom here when asking a question is to include information showing what you tried and where you are stuck. Although there is an answer, often you will just get downvotes and votes to close and hints like this one.

Answer (score 0):

"The product of $3$ and $c$ is $b$"

This means: $$3\times c=b\to c=\frac b3$$
"Which expression represents the sum of $c$ and $3$?"

This is asking: which of $$b+3$$
$$3b+3$$
$$3(b+3)$$
$$\frac{b+3}{3}$$
$$\frac b3+3$$
is equivalent to $$c+3$$
Given that $c=\frac b3$, the answer is obvious.

Comment: This is correct, but I wish you hadn't hurried to answer a question from a new user who showed no effort of his or her own. Better to comment pointing to the conventions on MSE.